# Не могу печатать информацию из mysql в веб сайт с помощю servlet

Tags: java

package manager

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from user");
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
        user.setName(resultSet.getString(2));
        user.setSurname(resultSet.getString(3));
        user.setEmail(resultSet.getString(4));
        user.setPassword(resultSet.getString(5));
        user.setPicUrl(resultSet.getString(6));
        users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
}
```

}

package serlvet

```
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/userHomeServlet")
public class UserHomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
        try {
            List<User> allUsers = userManager.getAllUsers();
            req.setAttribute("users", allUsers);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/userHome.jsp").forward(req,resp);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

web

```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>userHome</title>
</head>
<body>
<% List<User> users = (List<User>) request.getAttribute("users");%>
<%for (User user : users) {%>
<div><%=user.getName()%>
        <div><%=user.getSurname()%>
            <%}%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос точнее. что именно не получается? получаете исключение или нет, а если нет, то на каком именно этапе проблемы? Из БД получаете список юзеров?

Answer (score 0):

Начните с того, что приведите в порядок данные для заполнения юзера. Java это не PHP. Java строготипизированный язык.

И да, как уже вам верно подсказали - Покажите текст ошибки или что у вас там происходит.